# Stop numeric input being changed if aggregate JavaScript function goes negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript function which calculates the sum of numerous default numerical inputs, which provides a total value which I set to 0. If an input is increased by say 5, then my aggregate value will become -5, and vice versa for subtracting. What I want is that when a user wants to increase the value of an input, they must first decrease the value of another. My question is, how can I stop an input from increasing in value, if this would lead to a negative value in the total? Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLd7qwxy/), and my code is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  calculateSum(); //call the function here
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 309;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum -= parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#summation {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #174C68;
}

.txt {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="65" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Cheese</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="32" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Eggs</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="47" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Milk</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="31" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Bread</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="69" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Soap</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="65" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="summation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Sum :</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Preferably, the solution would stop the input from being altered, and show an error message if possible. Sorry if this seems quite basic, I've only just started using JS and don't have a clue where to start to achieve what I want.

Comment: The only way to stop this would be to use `[+][-]` buttons and not allow the user to type any value.   Otherwise once it's negative, there would be no way to make it positive again.

Comment: My users will be inputting numbers in the hundreds unfortunately, so I'm not sure I can go with this solution. You're quite sure theres no other way I could achieve this?

Comment: It depends on your concept of "input a number" - most questions/answers on SO seem to revolve around keypress/keyup which provides a *horrendous* UX.  So when has the user "input"?  On `blur`?   On pressing a `submit` type button?  Assuming on blur: store the current value, on blur check if the new total `<0` then if it is restore the current value and show an error message.

Comment: You can't "block" them from changing the value otherwise they won't be able to reduce it (eg if 15 makes it `<0` then 14 would be ok, but you've just blocked that input so they can't enter 14).    But if you stop the 15 in the first place by popping it back to 14 then fine, but you need to consider what constitutes an "input".

Comment: On blur would be a user clicking out of the input, is that correct? If so, that solution would work perfectly. Could your provide me a rough example that I can work on to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `blur` will trigger the check when the user leaves the input - either by tabbing out or by clicking in another input / clicking a button.

You can store the "current" value and then, in the blur handler, check if the sum becomes `<0` with the new value - if it does, you can restore the old value from the store.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  updateSum(calculateSum());

  $(".txt").each(function() {
    $(this).data("oldvalue", $(this).val());
  });

  $(".txt").on("blur", function() {
    var sum = calculateSum();
    if (sum < 0) {
      $(this).val($(this).data("oldvalue"));
      // show warning here, maybe highlight the dodgy input by setting background-colour etc (in a nice way, example here only)
      $("#warning").fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
      $(this).addClass("warning");
      var inp = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() { inp.removeClass("warning") }, 1000);
    } else {
      $(this).data("oldvalue", $(this).val());
      updateSum(sum);
    }
  });
});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 309;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum -= parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });

  return sum;
}

function updateSum(sum) {
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#summation {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #174C68;
}

.txt {
  background-color: #FEFFB0;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

#warning { color: red; }
.txt.warning { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="300px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#E8DCFF">
  <tr>
    <td width="40px">1</td>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="65" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Cheese</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="32" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Eggs</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="47" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Milk</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="31" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Bread</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="69" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Soap</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" value="65" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="summation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right">Sum :</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>
      <span id='warning' style='display:none;'>
          Please enter correct values
      </span>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: That's working perfectly. You've really gone beyond what I expected, that was probably the best answer I've had on SO. Thank you so much, your're an absolute boss.